# How to connect different panels?

Tags: java

I have created `JFrame` in NetBeans which has `mainPanel` and I have menu bar, by clicking the menu item the new `JPanel` class is displayed in `mainPanel` but I am getting problem to open new `JPanel` class from clicking the botton from older `JPanel` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
newjframe jf=new newjframe();
jf.setVisible(true);
```

This is the Jbutton action performed code